# What does the assembly code: mov edx, 2,3,4 do?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, masm

What does the assembly code: mov edx, 2,3,4 do? I have been trying to replicate it but nothing will take it as a legitimate operation I have a screen shot of where I saw it as-well.

![ida representation]https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhcMT.png

Comment: What CPU? In x86-64 there is no such instruction as `mov edx, 2,3,4`. As there is no such instruction, the question "what it does" does not make any sense. In x86-64 `mov` accepts only two operands, in Intel syntax: `mov dest, src`. What you are attempting to do?

Comment: The reference (where you saw it) would be helpful. I've never seen that syntax.

Comment: Are you the same person who asked [this question](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/2974/60)? We still haven't seen the paste of the code or a screenshot of the claimed instruction.

Comment: Added the image in the original post.

Comment: I think the question is, why does IDA decompile it like that.  I would use a different assembly editor and see what is "actually" there.  It might give a tip as to why IDA is showing it that way

Answer (score -2):

since your digits are small, it could be some compiler understands that and puts them into ax, ah, al   see http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~evans/cs216/guides/x86.html

but you havn't said where you got that from, so maybe you didn't get it right.

Comment: ax, ah, al wouldn't make sense because ax is a combination of ah and al. So the 2 would be overwritten. In any case, it's pretty weird syntax that I haven't ever seen before.

Comment: ... but the idea may be true so the instruction is identical to something like "mov eax,0x020304" or "mov eax,0x040302" or whatever combination of the bytes 02, 03 and 04 is possible.

Comment: @JimMischel yeah, I actually meant eax, (the high part), ah, al.  either way I think the  OP is confused. I've never seen that either.  Nice to get a couple downvotes out of it though.

Comment: Added the image in the original link. Not confused.